# MySQL - convert phone number data?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, data-structures

I have a MySQL InnoDB database.

I have a '`phone_number`' field.

My data is dirtly in the sense that sometimes my data is:

```
(111) 222-3333
111-222-3333
111.222.3333
(111) 222 3333
```

How can I strip all spaces and parenthesis from my '`phone_number`' field to only store my phone_number in the following format '`1112223333`'?

What would the SQL be to UPDATE my 'phone_number' field to have all data in the format '1112223333'?

For example, pseudo code:

```
UPDATE phone_number = STRIP_SPACES_AND_PARATENSIS(phone_number) FROM homes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sql query:

```
update homes set phone_number=replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_number,'-',''),'(',''),')',''),'.', ''), ' ', '');
```